# finding structure definition in qt creator

Tags: qt-creator, code-navigation

I'm trying to understand how one large programs work, and I coudn't think of anything better than running it in qt creator line by line.

I found the main function, now I'm trying to find a definition of one structure. I'm ctrl+clicking it, then it shows me the following:

```
struct TheName;
typedef struct TheName TheName;
```

Now how to find a real definition? I'm expecting someone to say "grep".

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it took you to the header file in which the object, `TheName`, is declared.  If you have access to the source code within your project you can press `F4` to "Switch Header/Source".  This can also be accessed directly by right clicking on the object name, `TheName`.